# How do I handle multi threading in Spring Boot while doing DB operations?

Tags: multithreading, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Following is the order in which I want to perform my DB operations:

1. Create an Entity of the newly arrived Information
2. Find if TABLE A contains a record using a unique name from the arrived information using DAO.
3. If it is present then `findBy` will return a entity,

   3.1 Using the entity returned after using `findBy` store it in TABLE A-History.

   3.2 Delete the record from TABLE A
4. Insert entity created using the new information in TABLE A.

How do I perform these operations in a **thread-safe** way in Spring Boot?

It works fine for some delete operations and fails for some. The `findBy()` query returns an old entity which has **already been deleted** from the database. I guess the results are getting cached. Hence the I get `StaleStateException` and it says that row count returned was 0 when 1 was expected.

Comment: Are you using Transactions?

Comment: where is your code ?

Comment: How does multithreading come into play?